# Spring SAML Security - future plans to support SAML AttributeQuery?

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I've been watching the old Spring IO JIRA ticket SES-142, https://jira.spring.io/browse/SES-142,  since July 2014. This JIRA ticket was a request to add support for the SAML2 AttributeQuery to the Spring SAML Security extension.

I just noticed today that the ticket was marked as completed and resolved, with no fix version, back on Feb 6. I don't see any related commits in the code, or any comments at all to the effect of "Won't be implemented".

Can someone from the Spring SAML Security team comment on the future, if any, of support for the AttributeQuery?  Adding attributes to the SAML Assertion returned from a SAML authentication doesn't work for my project - we need the ability to issue a separate AttributeQuery to the IdP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried asking on the page you are linking to? This question seems OT for SO.

Comment: Agreed, but unfortunately, I cannot add any comments to that ticket using my account on the Spring IO JIRA. And  apparently the old Spring IO discussion forum has been retired, and all community support issues are being redirected to SO, with a special tag spring-security.   This is the only venue I can find to ask the question without buying support from Pivotal :-(